# php setcookie after include

Tags: php, cookies, include

I would like to set a cookie using:

```
<?php 
   $cookie_ok = 1;
   setcookie("ICH_WILL_KEKSE",$cookie_ok,time()+(3600*24*365));
?>
```

This works so far.
However, using the following code throws an error:
""Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at ..."

```
<?php
   include "test.inc.php";
   setcookie("ICH_WILL_KEKSE",$cookie_ok,time()+(3600*25*365));
?>
```

test.inc.php:

```
<?php
   $cookie_ok = 1;
?>
```

It seem as if:

```
<?php

   <?php

   ?>

?>
```

already generates some output. So how can i include a file befor setting a cookie?

Comment: Thanks for the hint regarding the php close tag, this caused the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Cookies are set via headers, that's why you should not send any byte before setting.

Your include seems to output something. The most mistake is using a PHP close tag at the end, because then any whitespaces or newlines are output.

So for example, **omit** the close tag of **test.inc.php**

```
<?php
   $cookie_ok = 1;
```